# Equality between an improper integral and the sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Let $a>0$ we want to show that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{e^{at}-1}=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a^2n^2+1}$$

I assume that we want to find the power series expansion of $\dfrac{\sin(t)}{e^{at}-1}$ and then interchange the integral and the sum, but I was not able to find a closed formulafor the power series expansion, and I was only able to write the few first terms of the expansion which does not seem to have a clear pattern..

The second question is to find an equivalent to   $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{e^{at}-1}$ when $a\rightarrow \infty$.

My try $\dfrac{1}{n^2a^2+1}\sim \dfrac{1}{a^2n^2}$ hence

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{e^{at}-1}\sim \sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a^2n^2}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6a^2}$$ Is this correct?

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using this.
$${1\over e^{at} - 1} = {e^{-at} \over 1 - e^{-at}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-ant}.$$

Comment: So the sum $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{a^2n^2+1}$ in the identity I gave starts actually at $1$ not $0$?  and how to show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{e^{(i-an)t}}{i-an}=0$? what about the last equivalence I gave, is it correct ?

Comment: You can integrate $\int e^{at}\sin(bt)\,dt$ in the real domain. Just integrate by parts twice and back-solve for the integral.  Try that on each integral in the sum.